# Dynamic sounds not playing after two plays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have a little html5 application where you can play a sound by clicking a button.

I have a function that adds an `<audio>` tag to a `<div>` with an id "playing." The sound removes itself when it is done.

```
function sound(track){
$("#playing").append("<audio src=\"" + track + "\" autoplay onended=\"$(this).remove()\"></audio>");
}
```

For the button I have:

```
<button onclick="sound('sounds/tada.mp3')">Tada</button>
```

When I click the button, an `<audio>` briefly appears in the element inspector and disappears when it is finished, just the way I want it, but after triggering it two times, it just stops working in Chrome, at least. There are no errors in the console either.

What is going on?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle link?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EMngS/

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the onclick/onend in your HTML and reference the button in your js:

HTML

```
<button id='tada' sound_url='sounds/tada.mp3'>Tada</button>
```

And the JS

```
var sound = function(track){
   $("#playing").append("<audio id='played_audio' src='\" + track + \"' autoplay='true'></audio>");
}

$('#tada').on('click', function () {
   var sound_url = $(this).attr('sound_url');
   sound(sound_url);
});

$('#playing').on('end', 'played_audio', function() {
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, lets see..

```js
var audioURL = "http://soundbible.com/mp3/Canadian Geese-SoundBible.com-56609871.mp3";
var audioEl = null;

function removeAudio() {
  if (audioEl && audioEl.parentNode)
    audioEl.parentNode.removeChild(audioEl);
}

function sound() {
  removeAudio();
  audioEl = document.createElement("audio");
  audioEl.src = audioURL;
  audioEl.controls = true;
  audioEl.addEventListener("ended", removeAudio); // <-- Note it's ended, not end!
  document.getElementById("playing").appendChild(audioEl);
  audioEl.play();
}

document.getElementById("tada").addEventListener("click", sound);
```

```html
<div id="playing">
  
</div>
<button id="tada">Tada</button>
```

I'm not seeing any problems with this script.

1. Decide audioURL, set audioEl to null as it will be used later
2. When the element with ID `"tada"` is clicked, run our `sound` function.

   - Remove the audio.
   - Create the audio element.
   - When the audio is finished, remove the audio.
   - Append the audio to the element with ID `"playing"`.
   - Play the audio.

One thing to note is that I use the `ended` event, not the `end` event.

[(This answer is here because Andrew really wants us to answer it.)](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/post/1539340/)

Comment: Interesting! Let me go test it on my slow little netbook, which is apparently a factor in triggering the issue.